# Prove that this function is in $L^\infty$ with $\lVert g\rVert_\infty \le C$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

My professor used the following lemma in the proof that $L^1(X,\mu)^* = L^\infty(X,\mu)$ but left the proof as an exercise.

**Lemma**. Assume that $(X,\mathcal A, \mu)$ is a measure space and $g \in L^1(X,\mu)$. Suppose there is a constant $C > 0$ such that $$\left| \int_A g \, d\mu \,\right| \le C \mu(A)$$ for all $A \in \mathcal A$. Then $g \in L^\infty(X,\mu)$ and $\lVert g\rVert_\infty \le C$.

If $g$ is real-valued, the proof is relatively straight-forward but I am struggling to see how to prove this when $g$ is complex-valued. In that case, I can prove $\lVert g\rVert_\infty \le 2C$ but I am wondering how to get $\lVert g\rVert_\infty \le C$.

Comment: If $\mu (\{x :|g(x)|>C\}>0$ then $\mu (\{x: C+r\leq |g(x)| \leq C+s\}>0$ for some $s>r>0.$ Cover the annulus $ A=\{y :C+r\leq |y|\leq C+s\}$ with  a finite family $B$  of open balls of radius $d$ where $0<d<r/2$ and $d$ is arbitrarily small. For some $b\in B$ we have $\mu (g^{-1}(A\cap b))>0.$

Comment: I'm not sure how we can then conclude that $\left| \int_A g \, d\mu \right| > C\mu(A).$ Can you expand on your reasoning?

Comment: Let $A^*=g^{-1}(A\cap b)$. Then $ |\int_{A^*}g d\mu|>C\mu (A^*)$ if $d$ is small enough. I should not have called the annulus $A$ as that letter was already busy.